# VB6 Split String with < > Characters

Tags: string, vb6, split

I am trying to split something like this

When the Source is from a webpage and contains this value multiple times, but I don't think will split it because of the "<" character, any way around this?

```
SourceSplit = Split(Source, "<span class='BText' id='BText'>")
```

I tried using Chr(60) instead, didn't like that either, any ideas?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't know why you think the open angle bracket makes a difference. I tried your code and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420408/vb6-splitling-with-multi-multicharactered-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the HTML uses double quotes for attribute values, not single. You need to escape the double quotes:

```
SourceSplit = Split(Source, "<span class=""BText"" id=""BText"">")
```